# MySQL Database dump with complete schema and limited data

Tags: mysql, database, bash, dump

I have my client's complete database (size = approx. 80 GBs) on a remote server, such that I cannot retrieve it's complete schema(all tables, views, stored procedures etc.) along with data without server crashing or timing out.

So I need to build a script to dump complete MySQL Database's schema and conditionally limited dataset(eg. last 1 or 2 years records/rows) into a separate `.sql.gz` or `.sql.bz2` file.

Now I know how to export/dump complete database through the command line but I cannot figure out a way to set the data limit in the export script.

```
mysqldump -u <username> -p -A -R -E --triggers --single-transaction > full_backup.sql
```

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: You can use the `--where` option to specify a `WHERE` clause for the query that selects the rows to dump. This is generally only useful when dumping a  single table, since it's unlikely that the same condition will apply to all tables.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your comment, can you please explain this with examples in an answer or reference links, I am not so good with Linux/Unix bash commands and params.

Comment: `man mysqldump`

Answer (score 0):

The [`--where`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-filter-options) option can be used to filter the rows that are dumped. You give it a parameter containing the test that would go in the `WHERE` clause of a `SELECT` query.

```
mysqldump -u username -p --where='date > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR' databasename tablename > tablename.sql
```

This is not likely to work when dumping an entire database, rather than specific tables, because it's unlikely that all tables will have a `date` field that you want to filter identically.